# Debian will not play sound from speakers

Tags: debian, audio

Installed on partitioned HDD alongside Windows 10 my Debian 9.3 with Linux 4.9 (64-bit, also tried backported 4.14), and no sound.

In Windows 10, my sound works normally. On top of that, I have Debian on VirtualBox there (prior to installing it on a new partition) and although I had initially faced sound issues they were eventually resolved with a little tweaking (I cannot remember how exactly).

In my new Debian, I have tried playing Youtube videos from Firefox ESR and Google Chrome, then attempted to play WAV files with aplay and used speaker-test with no luck. However, the beep command still lives up to its name, and when I plug in my earphones all sounds work normally.

All sound controls are unmuted and maxed out (pavucontrol, alsamixer, and the likes), both ALSA and PulseAudio are running with no apparent problems.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing PulseAudio as well as the entire distribution.

`pavucontrol` displays sound playing on its bar under AudioStreams when I play sounds (e.g. Youtube videos), Output Devices lists Built-in Audio Analog Stereo, and on Configuration tab the profile is set to Analog Stereo Duplex (though I have also tried Analog Stereo Output).

Some of the pertinent outputs:

```
lspci | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)


lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          40960  9
snd_hda_codec         151552  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_pcm               118784  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd                    94208  26 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm

cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xb4428000 irq 134
```

P.S. Other answers I've seen included usage of alsa-base and alsactl, which apt-get cannot locate for me.